# Are placebos permitted without telling the person they are getting one?

Tags: halacha, medicine, gezel-stealing, sheker-false

Does Judaism allow placebos where the person thinks it does something, and is thereby cured, even though the item does nothing?

Is this gnevas da'as (or some other issur), or because it can help them it's permitted to mislead them this way.

Comment: Aren't you required to tell patients that they might be getting placebo?

Comment: @DoubleAA, that seems to be the question here.

Comment: @msh210 I meant US law, not halacha.

Comment: @DoubleAA I think the asker is asking about practice on the surface of the moon.

Comment: I'm saying in the US at least (and probably most Western countries), this is not an issue of Geneivat Daat because people know what the deal is

Comment: @DoubleAA, sure, but I think it's reasonable to understand the question as "in a domain where secular law has no such requirement...".  Should that be edited into the question Ariel?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Nowhere in the question does it say "In the United States", it said "Does Judaism". I don't know why DoubleAA even brought up US law. And in any case it's not so obvious that it's required in the US anyway. When they do studies they will sometimes write the placebos name in some technical way hoping people do not know what it is without outright lying. And it's currently a big debate if doctors should be allowed to prescribe them - but anecdotally, they already do. It's not unusual for doctors to prescribe some pill that does nothing to someone with psychosomatic illness.

Comment: @Ariel, I agree that the scope of the question is not just the US.  (I assume questions are global unless limited.)  I was just trying to cut off all considerations of secular law anywhere, but I see your point that the question already does that.  (And I had already upvoted it.)

Comment: If you tell them it is a placebo, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

[Nishmat Avraham](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578197125.html) writes on this (vol 2, p.12)

> [Placebo trials] are permissible provided that
>
> - the patient gives his full consent after being fully informed of the possible risks and that he may be put into one of other group
>     randomly
> - all patients, regardless of which group they will belong to, will continue to receive the medication they were getting until now. The
>     experimental drug or placebo is merely added to their present
>     treatment

PS. As a reminder the author, Dr. Abraham S. Abraham, is a leading physician in Israel. He doesn't address "the law of the land" in his response